# how to send a file to an external api in laravel job?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, api

I want to upload an image from a mobile app and send that file to Laravel API then, I want to send that image to an external API for getting information from pictures. In the controller I have the following code:

```
public function processImage(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif'
        ]);
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $filePath = $file->store('temp');
        ProcessImageJob::dispatch($filePath);

        $jobStatusId = 1;

        return response()->json(compact('jobStatusId'));
    }
```

In `ProcessImageJob` I call the API like this:

```
$client = new Client();
        $response = $client
            ->post($uploadUrl, [
                'headers' => $this->authHeaders,
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name'     => 'files',
                        'contents' => fopen($this->image, 'r'),
                        'headers'  => [ 'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']
                    ],
                ]
            ]);
        $response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

when I request, it gives in the queue terminal this error: `fopen(temp/XLCeHZJqkmwtyIhJ75rgDNTbXIhrlmncsvqTvvkD.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory`  how to fix this error? I appreciate any help.

P.S: For Laravel app, I use sail for docker.

Comment: have you checked if the file exists? if yes, try using `base_path()` in `fopen(base_path($this->image), 'r'),` or `storage_path()` if that is where the file is.

Comment: @N69S I tried both functions and it didn't work

Comment: and the file exists right ?